# Nginx: expires header becomes 404

Tags: nginx

I'm having problems with the expires header. When I set the expires and access the file through the browser it becomes Not Found 404.

Here is my virtual server setup on nginx.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name blgourl.com www.blogourl.com

  location / {
      root    /data/file/static/blogourl;
      index   index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }


  location ~* \.php$ {
  ssi on;
  root /data/file/static;
  fastcgi_param HTTP_USER_AGENT  $http_user_agent;
  fastcgi_index   index.php;
  #fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
  #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
  fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
  include         fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /data/file/static/blogourl$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

  }

}
```

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls#Root_inside_Location_Block

Comment: @AlexeyTen I see no error with 'service nginx configtest'

Comment: It's not an syntax error, but logical error. Nginx location's are excusive, so for your static files you don't have root directive and it sets to some weird internal default (`/etc/nginx/html` or something like that). Of course there is no your files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Alexey Ten said, root inside location is bad because you must define `root` parameter inside every location directive. And if forget to add the `root` in one of your location, nginx will set `root` [to default](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) `/etc/nginx/html`

Instead you must define [root outside your location](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block), e.g. in server directive. You can always add `root` in your location whenever your root directory changed. For example in your config, you can override `root` parameter inside `location ~* \.php$`

See also [this discussion](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,242986,242989#msg-242989) regarding **root inside location** issue.

Your config should be

```
  root    /data/file/static/blogourl;
  location / {
      index   index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico)$ {
      expires 30d;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }


  location ~* \.php$ {
      ssi on;
      root /data/file/static;
      fastcgi_param HTTP_USER_AGENT  $http_user_agent;
      fastcgi_index   index.php;
      #fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
      #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      include         fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME    /data/file/static/blogourl$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;

  }
```